equivalent definition of homological orientation
I read Hatcher definition of orientation on a (topological) manifold $M$, which is the following:
A global orientation on $M$ is a function $x \mapsto \mu_x \in H_n(M,M\smallsetminus\{x\}) = H_n(M|x)$ such that for each $x \in M$ there esists a chart $(U,\varphi)$ and a coordinate ball centered at $x$ such that for every $y \in B$, $\mu_y$ is the image of one generator $\mu_B \in H_n(M|B)$ via the map $H_n(M|B) \rightarrow H_n(M|y)$ induced by inclusion.
I'm wondering if this could be rephrased saying that a global orientation is an element of the orientation sheaf $o_M$ whose germ at each point generates the stalk $o_{M,x} = H_n(M|x)$, where for me the orientation sheaf is the sheafification of the presheaf which assigns to each $U \subseteq M$ the group $H_n(M|U)$. This last statement means that for each point there is a neighborhood $U$ where $f_x$ is of the form $\mu_U$ for a fixed element $\mu_U \in H_n(M|U)$. Clearly this seems weaker than the former definition, but also easier to work with, hence I was hoping to find out these two are actually equivalent. That is, I'd like to know if given an element $f \in o_M$ as in the latter definition, one could prove $f$ always satisfies the consistency property in the first definition. Any help?

What is $B$? Does it help to note that if $U$ is a ball around $x$ then $(M, M - U) \to (M, M - x)$ is an isomorphism on homology? If $M$ is a manifold there is of course a local basis of balls around $x$.

It is helpful to know the etale space - sheaf correspondence; then sheafification has a very nice interpretation. We may describe the global sections of the orientation sheaf (as you define it) as the group (under pointwise addition) of continuous maps $f:M\to\mathcal{O}$ with $\pi f=1_M$, $\pi:\mathcal{O}\to M$ the etale bundle associated to the homological orientation presheaf $U\mapsto H_n(M,M\setminus U;\Bbb Z)$. The space $\mathcal{O}$ is set-theoretically the disjoint union of all germs of this presheaf at all points of $M$, homology classes in some $H_n(M|U)$ where $x\in U$ which are identified with all their restrictions to some $H_n(M|V)$, $x\in V\subseteq U$. What are the stalks of this presheaf? Well, there's an obvious map $\varinjlim_{U\ni x}H_n(M|U)\to H_n(M|x)$ and as $M$ is a manifold, we may use excision to check it is an isomorphism in the following way.
Choose a chart $\Omega\cong\Bbb R^n$, $\Omega$ an open neighbourhood of $x$, which identifies $x$ with the origin. Consider that the set of bounded open discs about the origin in $\Bbb R^n$ pulls back to a cofinal family $S$ of neighbourhoods of $x$, so the map I describe is an isomorphism iff. $\varinjlim_{U\in S}H_n(M|S)\to H_n(M|x)$ is an isomorphism. But by excision I only need to care about $\varinjlim_{\delta>0}H_n(\Bbb R^n|B_\delta(0))\to H_n(\Bbb R^n|0)$. If you look at the LES on reduced homology of the pairs for these groups you realise $H_{n-1}(\Bbb R^n\setminus B_\delta(0))\overset{\cong}{\to}H_{n-1}(\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\})$ being an isomorphism seals the deal; each map $H_n(\Bbb R^n|B_\delta(0))\cong H_n(\Bbb R^n|x)$ is an isomorphism, and they are compatible with the restriction/inclusion morphisms as $\delta$ varies.
Hence we can identify $\mathcal{O}=\bigsqcup_{m\in M}H_n(M|m)$ as a set. It is topologised by the basis of opens $\{\xi|_m\in H_n(M|m)\,|\,m\in U\}$ where $\xi\in H_n(M|U)$ and $U$ is some open set. A global section is then exactly a function as Hatcher describes, a mapping $x\mapsto\mu_x\in H_n(M|x)$, with a continuity condition. We only have to see Hatcher's continuity condition agrees with the condition $M\to\mathcal{O}$ is continuous. This is trivial, however, if you are used to the topology on the etale space of a (pre)sheaf. The "coordinate balls" $B$ are a basis for the topology on $M$, and Hatcher's condition is equivalent to continuity if we topologise $\mathcal{O}$ with the basis $\{\xi|_m\in H_n(M|m)\,|\,m\in B\}$ among coordinate balls $B$... but this is the same topology, clearly.
Hence Hatcher-orientations are identifiable with global sections of this homological orientation sheaf. You could work in ring coefficients for any ring other than $\Bbb Z$, too.
